# Algoritmo de fatorial em Portugol Studio

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Eu tenho esse algoritmo:

```
programa 
{
    inteiro numero, fatorial, resultado=1

    funcao inicio() 
    {
        escreva ("Insira um número a ser fatorado: ")
        leia (numero)

        para (fatorial = 1; fatorial <= numero; fatorial++)
        {
            resultado = resultado * fatorial
        }

        escreva ("O fatorial de ", numero, " é: ", resultado)
    }
}
```

Que me retorna corretamente o fatorial. Mas como que eu faço pra ele retornar toda a matemática?

Ex.:

> **5! = 5x4x3x2x1=120**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa ter em mente é que o *loop* (`para`) precisa estar ao contrário. Isso porque vai ficar mais fácil para concatenar as multiplicações numa *string* (variável do tipo `cadeia`).

Por exemplo, o fatorial de **3** tem resultado **6** a representação seria **3! = 3x2x1 = 6**. Perceba que é bem mais fácil fazer a concatenação do texto se a multiplicação começar pelo **3**.

Tendo isto em mente, segue o algoritmo

```
inteiro numero, fatorial, resultado = 1
cadeia texto = "" //Variavel para salvar a representação final (3x2x1)

escreva ("Insira um número a ser fatorado: ")
leia (numero)

/* Perceba que aqui o loop (para), corre de trás pra frente. Ou seja, ele começa no número
 * que foi digitado pelo usuário (fatorial = numero), acontece enquanto o multiplicador 
 * for maior ou igual a 1 (fatorial >= 1) e vai diminuindo 1 do multiplicador 
 * a cada passada (fatorial--) */

para (fatorial = numero; fatorial >= 1; fatorial--)
{
    // Aqui, se for 1 não precisamos concatenar o sinal de multiplicação (x)
    se(fatorial == 1){
        texto = texto + fatorial
    }senao{
        texto = texto + fatorial + "x"
    }

    resultado = resultado * fatorial
}

escreva (numero, "! = ", texto, " = ", resultado)
```

Comment: Rapaz é isso aí mesmo! Eu preciso melhorar a minha lógica! Eu já tinha desistido desse algoritmo! Vlw jbueno!

Comment: @SandsonCosta Por nada. Sempre que precisar pode postar aqui, as vezes demora um pouco, mas perguntas bem feitas sempre serão respondidas.

Answer (score 0):

```
texto t = ""
para (fatorial = numero; fatorial >= 1; fatorial--) //Realiza o decremento
{
    if(fatorial != 1){ //Verifica se diferente de 1 para não adicionar o "x"
       t = t + fatorial + "x"
    } else {
       t = t+ fatorial
    }
    resultado = resultado * fatorial
}
escreva (fatorial, "! = ",t , " = ", resultado)
```

//Fazem anos que não vejo portugol

Comment: O que seria esse texto t = " " ?

Comment: Eu fiz aqui o código... não deu o resultado direito...

Comment: @Sandson Costa esse t="" é a cadeia que irá definir o caracter ou a palavra em específico