# Ajuda com programação em Portugol

Tags: portugol

Sou iniciante e preciso resolver um problema envolvendo estruturas de repetições controladas.

O problema é esse: Um jogador da Mega Sena quer saber todas as combinações possíveis que o jogo permite e o total delas.

Dados:

Cada cartela tem 20 dezenas

1 aposta contém 6 dezenas.

tentei dessa forma:

```
algoritmo semNome;

    // Síntese

    //  Objetivo:  Saber todas as combinações possíveis e total de combinações da Mega Sena

    //  Entrada :  

    //  Saída   :


principal

    // Declarações
    inteiro a , b, c, d, r, f;
    inteiro nc;
    inteiro totdez;


    // Instruções
    totdez=20;
    nc=1;
    para (a de 1 ate totdez passo 1) faca
        para (b de a+1 ate totdez passo 1) faca
                para (c de 3 ate totdez passo 1) faca
                     para (d de c+1 ate totdez passo 1) faca
                            para (r de 5 ate totdez passo 1) faca
                                 para (f de r+1 ate totdez passo 1) faca
                                    escreval("Cartela n°", nc," ", a,",", b,",", c,",", d,",", r,",", f);
                                    nc = nc +1;

                                fimPara
                            fimPara
                    fimPara
                fimPara
        fimPara
    fimPara
    nc = nc - 1;
    escreval("O número total de resultados de ", totdez," é:", nc,".");

fimPrincipal
```

Em si ele funciona mas as dezenas vão se repetindo e ficando infinitas.

OBS: Esse programa foi desenvolvido pela própria faculdade, porém é quase a mesma coisa que o visual.

Comment: Posso não ter entendido direito seu problema,porém não é só fazer um fatorial de nc? ou seja, fatorial de 20...?

Comment: Oi, como eu poderia fazer esse fatorial do nc?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197661/algoritmo-de-fatorial-em-portugol-studio esse link irá te sanar as dúvidas do fatorial em portugol

Comment: Cada comando para parte da variável do para anterior acrescido de 1. O final também vai variando no primeiro para até totdez-5 chegando a todez-1 no para mais interno.